# Trim and return any type

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

i've developed this basic method which i hoped would be able to trim and return any type:

```
public static object TrimValue<T>(T arg, int MaxLength)
{
    var val = arg.ToString();

    var trimVal = val.Substring(0, MaxLength);

    return Convert.ChangeType(trimVal, arg.GetType());
}
```

Use:

```
    double aDouble = 1000;

    double cDouble = TrimValue(aDouble, 2);
```

Unfortunately i get the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'double'

A cast would work but i might be trimming a Double, String or Int so that wont work. Does anyone have any idea how to trim a generic value?

Thanks

Comment: What does "trimming a double to 2" even mean?  Meaning it changes `1000 ` to `10`?  What would `TrimValue(new DateTime(2016,12,1),3)` return? How can trimming be applied to anything but strings?

Comment: Hence it's converted to a string in TrimValue()! This is to ensure data is not sent to an external source with a values that are too long, is doesn't matter what the data is!

Comment: @DanHall Then why isn't the return type `string` or why don't you have the return type set to `T`?

Comment: You're also going to run into issues when `MaxLength` is greater then the length of the `val` string.

Comment: Good point, that's where I'm going wrong, Eshans current answer looks good.

Comment: I hope you're not expecting to use this for String[] or List<DateTime>. Or even a bool...

Comment: The MaxLength isn't an issue, the val vs MaxLength problem is handled outside of this method, thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: @PeterB just for Double, Int, String and Decimal

Comment: But "trimming" a number makes no sense since it changes the value.  If a client wants to send a number that's too big, then implicitly "trimming" it would send a different value.  Plus trying to change a "trimmed" string representation back to the original type seems very brittle.  "1.2E3" is a valid `double` string, but "1.2E" is not.  "2016-12-01" is a valid date string but "2016-0" is not.  Maybe you've got other safeguards in place to prevent that, but on the surface it seems bizarre.

Comment: I understand the concerns but in this case it makes sense as for and int/double I'm only ever trimming zeros from the end (which isn't altering the required value)

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is not correct,instead of returning `object` change it to return the specific generic type passed by the caller using `T`:

```
public static T TrimValue<T>(T arg, int MaxLength)
{
    var val = arg.ToString();

    var trimVal = val.Substring(0, MaxLength);

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(trimVal, arg.GetType());
}
```